# How to convince team members not to use singletons?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm a member of team which has grown considerably during the last two years. Three members of "the old team" have been working for more than two years on a library, which now the rest of the team has to use. They have invested a lot of ego into that library. Unfortunately it turned out to be littered with singletons.

The singletons are making it impossible for us to write testable code. TDD is important for some of the team members, but only tolerated by the three library creators. So far we have tried the following to convince them to get rid of the singletons:

- Pointed out problems with singletons (global state, tight coupling, difficult to test)

  - Objections were rejected, because current code works.
- Demonstrated that our tests (which use the library/singletons) fail from time to time

  - Rejected, because we obviously "do not know how to work with singletons"
- Provided alternative implementation

  - Rejected, because their current code already works
- Talked together with superior about problems

  - Superior is not a software developer and has to choose between two "valid" views onto the problem. Trusts older team members more.

We have to use that library, because it has already replaced a central part of our program. Do you see any other way to tackle the situation?

Comment: even i am not sold on tests with these singletons will fail from time to time ??? How do they occasionally fail ?

Comment: Throw bananas at them. But really, you can't reason with pattern fanboys, especially singleton fanboys.

Comment: The "do not know how to test singletons" part is odd - because it sounds like you're not *trying* to test the singletons, you're trying to test code which *uses* the singletons.

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: Singletons can be seen as having a global state. Accessing a singleton in a test can change its state. For any given test the state of the singleton now depends on the number of accesses to the singleton performed by other tests. Now it is at least difficult (not to say impossible) to always have the same starting point when the test is executed. Depending on what you test, it might pass or fail.

Comment: @Yarc: Sounds like these singletons fail because they're designed incorrectly, not because of an inherent flaw in the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems with the code base of the library will not be solved with technical arguments or technical approaches. To solve your issues with the singletons a pure technical solution will work for now. But if you want to convince the "old" team to not use singletons and to work together with the rest of the team, to take your concerns seriously you'll definitely need more than tech.

Try to see the whole situation from their point of view. They were working hard for two years to implement that library the knowledge base they had and hopefully liked that work. And now your "new" team is coming and telling them that the implementation, they invested two years of their live, is technical bullshit. How would you react in that situation? Say, uh thanks, these singletons are really the worst pattern we used? No, not really...

I'd recommend you to read [Driving Technical Change](http://pragprog.com/book/trevan/driving-technical-change) and try to find a strategy how to convince them. In the meanwhile my best advice is: Honor their work, try to see the situation from their perspective, try to convince one by one - not the team and build a wrapper around that "legacy" code.

Answer (score 2):

(You haven't stated your language or platform, so I'll use C# as an example. I'd expect the same principles to apply for others though.)

Do you get to create your own interfaces and implementations of those interfaces which delegate appropriately? Even if the library designers are unwilling to implement an interface, you can always delegate:

```
// Existing code
public class FooSingleton
{
    public static FooSingleton Instance { get { ... } }

    public void Bar()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class SingletonDelegatingFoo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        FooSingleton.Instance.Bar();
    }
}
```

Then you use normal dependency injection (or whatever) to make your own code testable, only relying on `IFoo` - and you inject a `SingletonDelegatingFoo` when running the full system.

(As an aside, are these singletons even implemented correctly? You may get more buy-in if you can show that the singleton pattern is not only sucky from a testing point of view, but can also be implemented badly...)

Comment: Thanks for the idea (and it is C++ btw). For the moment I do not care whether they are implemented correctly, because I do not want to give them more ideas. I have read Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ design" and seen how difficult it can be, but I really do not like to see them using these ideas.

Comment: @Yarc: Not even if an incorrect implementation gives ammunition for removing the pattern completely? Why would you *not* care for that reason?

Comment: They would only implement a corrected version of the singleton. We have already seen them fixing the obvious problems :-(

Comment: Although isolating from the library is an option, I would rather see both sides agreeing on a solution without singletons. The next library will have another singleton otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach of an experienced developer is to update their CV/resume and start looking around for another job before it is realized that the system cannot be made reliable enough for delivery, is delivered anyway and becomes a never-ending crock of not-gold that someone has to continually maintain.  The 'someone' should be one of the older developers with 40 years of pension-entitlement to protect - 'an offer he/she can't refuse'.

Maybe I'm being over-cynical because my latest project has itself turned into a crock of not-gold overnight after an innocuous change, or maybe I remember what happened decades ago when I stood up in a review meeting and stated 'This job cannot possibly work as it's designed', (ever since that experience, I've just got out early, or done it as a contract job).

Comment: It sounds like the questioner's environment many not be interested in retaining top talent.  Also, often more political capital can be gained in this scenario by putting a workable solution on the back burner, being quiet until there is a problem and then capitalizing on a crisis.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you have to treat that library as an external dependency of your code (like a 3rd party library) and code accordingly.

That means, as Jon Skeet mentioned, design your code to be isolated and testable *without* the external library. Design a couple of interfaces (pure virtual classes) that capture the required contracts that you expect them to fulfill, and also write a couple of integration tests that exercise the communication between your code and that library. Ideally, the communication surface should be kept as small as possible, maybe only relegated to a couple of adapters or bridges that implement your interfaces.

Then it becomes a problem of "contract" negotiation, where you'd point out parts of the library that don't work as expected and (hopefully) wait for a fix or adapt your code accordingly. You might surface bugs and semantic mismatches this way, which might prompt parallel evolution of your code and the library.

If your code is the only *consumer* of that library, you should get to dictate what is expected of it, and it should adapt to *your* needs, not the other way around. If they then provide the service you expect, the fact that they use singletons or whatnot becomes irrelevant.